# sqlalchemy Object with OrderingList - Session.commit() method fails

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Model that has attribute in type of sqlalchemy [OrderingList](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html?highlight=orderinglist#sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist.OrderingList) fails on Database Session Commit step (as Database I am using PostgreSQL 13):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from database.base_class import Base
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list


class ContentType(Enum):
    SCENE_HEADING = 'scene_heading'
    ACTION = 'action'
    CHARACTER = 'character'
    PARENTHETICAL = 'parenthetical'
    DIALOGUE = 'dialogue'
    SHOT = 'shot'
    TRANSITION = 'transition'
    TEXT = 'text'


class EditorElement(Base):
    """
    Class that represents the Table of Editor Elements.
    """
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    content = Column(String, nullable=True)
    content_type = Column(ContentType, nullable=True)

    screenplay_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('screenplays.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)

    screenplay = relationship("Screenplay", back_populates="elements")


class Screenplay(Base):
    """
    Class that represents the screenplay table in the database.
    """
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)
    elements = relationship("EditorElement", back_populates="screenplay", order_by="EditorElement.content_type",
                            collection_class=ordering_list('content_type'))
```

I am using FastAPI framework and in the CRUD file where the `Screenplay` is created, I have the following class:

```
class CRUDScreenplay(CRUDBase[models.Screenplay, schemas.ScreenplayBase, schemas.ScreenplayBase]):

    @staticmethod
    def create(db: Session, *, obj_in: schemas.ScreenplayCreate) -> models.Screenplay:
        db_obj = models.Screenplay()
        db_obj.name = obj_in['name']

        for element in obj_in.get('elements'):
            e = models.EditorElement(
                content=element.content,
                content_type=element.content_type,
                screenplay_id=db_obj.id
            )
            db_obj.elements.append(e)

        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
```

Using the PyCharm debugger I was able to check when the error occurs, it seems to appear after `Session.commit()`. Here is the object `elements` before the `commit()` method

[image]

And here is the `elements` object after the `commit()` method.

[image]

And the error in the console:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52649 - "POST /api/v1/screenplays/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 1649, in _object_value_for_elem
    return self._object_lookup[elem]
KeyError: 'scene_heading'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 372, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 261, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 84, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 235, in app
    response_data = await serialize_response(
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 130, in serialize_response
    value, errors_ = await run_in_threadpool(
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 28, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(func, *args, cancellable=cancellable,
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 818, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 754, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 854, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.validate
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 1071, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._validate_singleton
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 1118, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._apply_validators
  File "pydantic\class_validators.py", line 313, in pydantic.class_validators._generic_validator_basic.lambda12
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 678, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.validate
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 562, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.from_orm
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 1001, in pydantic.main.validate_model
  File "pydantic\utils.py", line 409, in pydantic.utils.GetterDict.get
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 481, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(state, dict_)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 941, in get
    value = self._fire_loader_callables(state, key, passive)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 977, in _fire_loader_callables
    return self.callable_(state, passive)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\strategies.py", line 911, in _load_for_state
    return self._emit_lazyload(
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\strategies.py", line 1051, in _emit_lazyload
    result = result.unique().scalars().all()
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1371, in all
    return self._allrows()
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 401, in _allrows
    rows = self._fetchall_impl()
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1284, in _fetchall_impl
    return self._real_result._fetchall_impl()
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1696, in _fetchall_impl
    return list(self.iterator)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 147, in chunks
    fetch = cursor._raw_all_rows()
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 393, in _raw_all_rows
    return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 393, in <listcomp>
    return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 1768, in process
    value = self._object_value_for_elem(value)
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 1651, in _object_value_for_elem
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\userh\Playground\screenplay-writer\backend\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
LookupError: 'scene_heading' is not among the defined enum values. Enum name: None. Possible values: None
```

However, the data was successfully created in the database, but FastAPI does not return anything due to this error.

There are some related issues in GitHub but I am was not able to figure out what is going on there:

1. [Issue 1](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7592)
2. [Issue 2](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7590)
3. [Issue 3](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5658)
4. [Issue 4](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7418)

**UPDATE**

Alembic (which is often used with FastAPI) or SLQAlchemy created the PostgreSQL ENUM Type in Uppercase.

[image]

I changed the definition of `ContentType(enum.Enum)` as it was in the example of the official documentation [LINK](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html?highlight=enum#sqlalchemy.types.Enum). Thanks to @fchancel for pointing on that:

```
class ContentType(str, enum.Enum):
    HEADING = 'HEADING'
    ACTION = 'ACTION'
    CHARACTER = 'CHARACTER'
    PARENTHETICAL = 'PARENTHETICAL'
    DIALOGUE = 'DIALOGUE'
    SHOT = 'SHOT'
    TRANSITION = 'TRANSITION'
    TEXT = 'TEXT'
```

So, now my code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when creating your elements, the `content_type` section is a problem, since it can't find `heading_scene`. To understand this, we need to see how you call your function and what `obj_in` contains.

However, it's possible that the source of the error is just your `class ContentType(Enum)` which to work properly should be `class ContentType(str, Enum)`

Comment: Note the UPDATE part of the post. Thank you!